# ¿Como cerrar una ventana modal automaticamente?

Tags: php, html5, bootstrap

Quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de cerrar una ventana modal, sin dar clic en "Cerrar"?, por ejemplo, si la ventana es un formulario y devuelve un mensaje de Envio exitoso, estaria bueno que se cierre automaticamente luego de 2 segundos.

Comment: Lo que necesitas es usar alertify el crea un mensaje en una especie de modal y la cierra

Comment: Deberias agregar tu codigo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Te recomendaría utilizar la librería de *sweetalert* es muy buena para enviar mensajes sin necesidad de dar clic en algún botón.

```js
 swal({
  title: "¡mensaje!",
  timer: 2000 ,
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.0/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Coloca una explicación, las respuestas que son solo código generalmente se consideran de baja calidad